# How to serialize an Object into a list of URL query parameters?

Tags: javascript

Without knowing the keys of a JavaScript `Object`, how can I turn something like...

```
var obj = {
   param1: 'something',
   param2: 'somethingelse',
   param3: 'another'
}

obj[param4] = 'yetanother';
```

...into...

```
var str = 'param1=something&param2=somethingelse&param3=another&param4=yetanother';
```

...?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
var str = "";
for (var key in obj) {
    if (str != "") {
        str += "&";
    }
    str += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
}
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/WFPen/

Comment: Why not use a function with recursion?

Comment: @Jared: in JavaScript, recursive solutions are usually dreadfully slow in comparison with their iterative counterparts. Usually.

Comment: @Reid - Recursion is potentially problematic, but why would Javascript have a issue unless it was several levels deep?

Comment: @Jared - Because from the question it did not appear that the object was intended to be more than a single level deep.  If the goal is to serialize an arbitrary JavaScript object into a query string, then a recursive solution may be appropriate.  But I didn't get the impression that that's what was being asked for here.

Comment: @aroth - Yes, hence my comment under the question. :) I'm just thinking about utility, but I suppose it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks @aroth! I only accepted @patrick's answer above over yours (they are essentially the same) because he was first, I believe. I'm very grateful for your response.

Comment: @bobsoap: I think @aroth was a little ahead of me, so I'd give @aroth the tick all other things being equal.

Comment: Should theoretically use `hasownproperty`, but in real life, not really. http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty

Comment: Shouldn't the obj[key] be wrapped in encodeURIComponent()? What happens if 'somethingelse' was 'something&else'?

Comment: @JamesS yes it should, this fixes it `Object.keys(formData).map(key => [key, formData[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join('=')).join('&')`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should *not* be the accepted answer, or nearly every answer on this stackoverflow thread. Primary reason being none of them with the exception of possible @zac's answer below will satisfy properly encoding this object, `{ a:[ 1, 2 ], b:{ c:3, d:[ 4, 5 ], e:{ x:[ 6 ], y:7, z:[ 8, 9 ] }, f:true, g:false, h:undefined }, i:[ 10, 11 ], j:true, k:false, l:[ undefined, 0 ], m:"cowboy hat?" };` It does look like @UnLoCo suggested an NPM library that will also work, which pulls the functioning param method out of jQuery to be standalone.

Comment: @Wes agreed, the only solid answer here is jfunk's.

Comment: @Wes Point taken, although the OP asks about doing this with "something like" a simple object where each key-value pair maps to a param name and param value (as a string).  Honestly I don't know why you'd want to use this approach with a complex object in the first place.  If the object you want to send contains nested objects and arrays it's almost certainly better to `JSON.stringify()` the root object and just send the entire JSON string as the request body.  Whomever is writing your server-side code to parse this stuff will thank you, guaranteed. :)

Answer (score 305):

One line with no dependencies:

```
new URLSearchParams(obj).toString();
// OUT: param1=something&param2=somethingelse&param3=another&param4=yetanother
```

Use it with the URL builtin like so:

```
let obj = { param1: 'something', param2: 'somethingelse', param3: 'another' }
obj['param4'] = 'yetanother';
const url = new URL(`your_url.com`);
url.search = new URLSearchParams(obj);
const response = await fetch(url);
```

[Edit April 4, 2020]: `null` values will be interpreted as the string `'null'`.

[Edit Mar 9, 2022]: [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Note: in node < 10 you'll need to import/require e.g., `const { URLSearchParams } = require("url");`

Comment: @HonsaStunna I've never thought about putting multidimensional objects on a URL parameter, usually use POST with JSON for that

Comment: Be careful with this one and null values.

Comment: You should check if your target browsers to suport URLSearchParams, e.g. IE11 does not: https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams

Comment: Is there a way where we can use a different separator rather than default one '&'?

Comment: Could you update your question to a runnable code? 10x

Comment: I find your answer elegant but I needed a one-liner that could check null. So here's an implementation that checks null and undefined
```Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, val]) => val != null && val != undefined).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`).join('&');```

Comment: will not work with nested objects

Comment: this doesn't support nested objects

Comment: ISO dates are parsed wrongly. Here is result: `date=2023-03-24T15%3A10%3A01.511Z`. `:` are replaced with special characters

Comment: This does not work if you use `axios.url(url)`... You need to write one additional line.

Answer (score 150):

If you use jQuery, this is what it uses for parameterizing the options of a GET XHR request:

```
$.param( obj )
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Most of the other ansers were no good for a nested object. This one does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 149):

An elegant one: (assuming you are running a modern browser or node)

```
var str = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return key + '=' + obj[key];
}).join('&');
```

And the ES2017 equivalent: (thanks to Lukas)

```
let str = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`).join('&');
```

**Note:** You probably want to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) if the keys/values are not URL encoded.

Comment: I would only change `+ encodeURIComponent(obj[key])`

Comment: @JacobValenta that's not part of the question

Comment: Here it is in ES2015 `Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => \`${key}=${val}\`).join('&')`

Comment: This breaks down if the object has any nested properties.

Comment: To encode the ES2015 answer change to: `=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`

Comment: @SeantheBean Yup, though you can always `JSON.stringify` those objects beforehand if need be.

Comment: This won't work for array type params like `ids[]=1&ids[]=2`

Comment: @benweet it is part of the question; it's in the title: "url query parameters". Those require encoding. Otherwise a & in a value will create an invalid query parameter.

Comment: instead of map-join, you want to use reduce

Comment: @JanTuroň No, at least not for an easy-to-read one-liner.

Comment: `var str = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key,i,a) => acc + key + "=" + obj[key] + (i<a.length-1 ? "&" : ""), "");` - not a good idea for memory efficiency, but still readable one-liner, possibly useful for short objects where the hanging `&` doesn't matter (most of the cases), so `i` and `a` params can be omited.

Answer (score 33):

> ES2017 approach

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`).join('&')
```

Comment: [ES2017](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla), technically.

Comment: this needs encoding of both key and value. see other answers re encodeURIComponent.

Comment: also will not work with nested objects

Comment: I fixed the `encodeURIComponent` part but the nested object part still holds true. Although if you want to  serialize and send an object as a parameter to your key, the will still work

Answer (score 27):

ES6:

```js
function params(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`).join('&');
}

console.log(params({foo: 'bar'}));
console.log(params({foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux$'}));
```

Answer (score 22):

For one level deep...

```
var serialiseObject = function(obj) {
    var pairs = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }
        pairs.push(prop + '=' + obj[prop]);
    }
    return pairs.join('&');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLA7H/).

There was talk about a recursive function for arbitrarily deep objects...

```
var serialiseObject = function(obj) {
    var pairs = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) == '[object Object]') {
            pairs.push(serialiseObject(obj[prop]));
            continue;
        }
        pairs.push(prop + '=' + obj[prop]);
    }
    return pairs.join('&');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZyGS/).

This of course means that the nesting context is lost in the serialisation.

If the values are not URL encoded to begin with, and you intend to use them in a URL, check out JavaScript's [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: alex: Sorry, we're closed... ;o)

Comment: +1 for being safer than I'm willing to be: `.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

Comment: this is great - just need 1 level for now, but the recursive function is good to have. Thanks for adding it!

Comment: @ripper234 You're free to not use that method, if it suits your requirements.

Comment: This works: 
```
  const findOptions = {
    where: {id: facilityId.toString()},
    include: [
      serialiseObject({
        association: 'Insurances',
        where: {
          amount: '9.0000'
        }
      }),
    ]
  };
  const searchParams =  serialiseObject(findOptions);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're using NodeJS 13.1 or superior you can use the native querystring module to parse query strings.

```
const qs = require('querystring');
let str = qs.stringify(obj)
```

Comment: For apps watch out for breaking changes in Webpack 5. https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

Answer (score 8):

```
Object.keys(obj).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[k])}`).join('&')
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I made such a big deal about a recursive function, here is my own version.

```
function objectParametize(obj, delimeter, q) {
    var str = new Array();
    if (!delimeter) delimeter = '&';
    for (var key in obj) {
        switch (typeof obj[key]) {
            case 'string':
            case 'number':
                str[str.length] = key + '=' + obj[key];
            break;
            case 'object':
                str[str.length] = objectParametize(obj[key], delimeter);
        }
    }
    return (q === true ? '?' : '') + str.join(delimeter);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Kk3Lz/2/

Comment: Just some random thoughts (a) `[]` is preferred over `new Array()` (b) You can use `delimiter = delimiter || '&';` for the argument default (and you spelt it wrong) (c) Iterating with `for ( in )` will iterate over all enumerable properties, including things on the prototype chain (`obj.hasOwnProperty()` defends against this) (d) `typeof` can *lie* about what things are, e.g. some numbers can be `Object` if constructed with the `Number()` constructor (e) `Array` have a `push()` method for adding members (f) comparing to `true` is redundant. I am a nitpicky bastard but you wanted feedback! :)

Comment: ...and if you thing Crockford is right about everything, you shouldn't let switch cases fall through. I disagree with him on that though. :D

Comment: @alex - I appreciate it. a) I had that at first, it was late and I was sleepy; b) not sure what the improvement is, the second was also a sleep-deprived moment; c) I was wondering why you used `hasOwnProperty()`; d) that's certainly true and a good point; e) I've never gotten use to using `push()` or `pop()` methods; f) `break` or not to `break`, that is the question. Thank you for your detailed input. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record and in case you have a browser supporting ES6, here's a solution with `reduce`:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, key, i) => (
  `${prev}${i!==0?'&':''}${key}=${obj[key]}`
), '');
```

And here's a snippet in action!

```js
// Just for test purposes
let obj = {param1: 12, param2: "test"};

// Actual solution
let result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, key, i) => (
  `${prev}${i!==0?'&':''}${key}=${obj[key]}`
), '');

// Run the snippet to show what happens!
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

A useful code when you have the array in your query:

```
var queryString = Object.keys(query).map(key => {
    if (query[key].constructor === Array) {
        var theArrSerialized = ''
        for (let singleArrIndex of query[key]) {
            theArrSerialized = theArrSerialized + key + '[]=' + singleArrIndex + '&'
        }
        return theArrSerialized
    }
    else {
        return key + '=' + query[key] + '&'
    }
}
).join('');
console.log('?' + queryString)
```

Answer (score 4):

This one-liner also handles nested objects and `JSON.stringify` them as needed:

```
let qs = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(typeof (v) === "object" ? JSON.stringify(v) : v)}`).join('&')
```

Comment: Nice approach but it fails on this nesting: `{apple:['old'],['blue'],banana:['fresh','green']}` which should turn into something like `apple=old,blue&banana=fresh,green`

Comment: @Fred - Fails b/c `JSON.stringify` is expecting a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 4):

A quick ES6 answer:

```
const paramsObject = {
   foo: "bar",
   biz: "baz"
}

const params = Object.entries(paramsObject)
                 .map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`)
                 .join('&');

// Output: foo=bar&biz=baz
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a recursive function that will produce proper URL parameters based on the object given, try my Coffee-Script one.

```
@toParams = (params) ->
    pairs = []
    do proc = (object=params, prefix=null) ->
      for own key, value of object
        if value instanceof Array
          for el, i in value
            proc(el, if prefix? then "#{prefix}[#{key}][]" else "#{key}[]")
        else if value instanceof Object
          if prefix?
            prefix += "[#{key}]"
          else
            prefix = key
          proc(value, prefix)
        else
          pairs.push(if prefix? then "#{prefix}[#{key}]=#{value}" else "#{key}=#{value}")
    pairs.join('&')
```

or the JavaScript compiled...

```
toParams = function(params) {
  var pairs, proc;
  pairs = [];
  (proc = function(object, prefix) {
    var el, i, key, value, _results;
    if (object == null) object = params;
    if (prefix == null) prefix = null;
    _results = [];
    for (key in object) {
      if (!__hasProp.call(object, key)) continue;
      value = object[key];
      if (value instanceof Array) {
        _results.push((function() {
          var _len, _results2;
          _results2 = [];
          for (i = 0, _len = value.length; i < _len; i++) {
            el = value[i];
            _results2.push(proc(el, prefix != null ? "" + prefix + "[" + key + "][]" : "" + key + "[]"));
          }
          return _results2;
        })());
      } else if (value instanceof Object) {
        if (prefix != null) {
          prefix += "[" + key + "]";
        } else {
          prefix = key;
        }
        _results.push(proc(value, prefix));
      } else {
        _results.push(pairs.push(prefix != null ? "" + prefix + "[" + key + "]=" + value : "" + key + "=" + value));
      }
    }
    return _results;
  })();
  return pairs.join('&');
};
```

This will construct strings like so:

```
toParams({a: 'one', b: 'two', c: {x: 'eight', y: ['g','h','j'], z: {asdf: 'fdsa'}}})

"a=one&b=two&c[x]=eight&c[y][0]=g&c[y][1]=h&c[y][2]=j&c[y][z][asdf]=fdsa"
```

Comment: I think I'll hang it on the wall

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method:

```js
var obj = {
  param1: 'something',
  param2: 'somethingelse',
  param3: 'another'
}
obj['param4'] = 'yetanother';
var str = jQuery.param(obj);
alert(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A functional approach.

```js
var kvToParam = R.mapObjIndexed((val, key) => {
  return '&' + key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(val);
});

var objToParams = R.compose(
  R.replace(/^&/, '?'),
  R.join(''),
  R.values,
  kvToParam
);

var o = {
  username: 'sloughfeg9',
  password: 'traveller'
};

console.log(objToParams(o));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '';

for( var name in obj ) {
    str += (name + '=' + obj[name] + '&');
}

str = str.slice(0,-1);
```

Give this a shot.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/T2UWT/

Comment: @Jared: Less efficient than a loop.

Comment: @Jared: username not needed below Qs and As. Notifications are automatic.

Comment: "Less performant"? If I pass in an arbitrary object, and want a GET string to be returned, what does performance have to do with it?

Comment: @Jared: I'm sorry, but perhaps I'm not understanding your meaning. If you're suggesting the use of recursive function calls rather than a loop, then I'm quite certain that the recursive functions will perform more slowly than the loop. Have I misunderstood your point?

Comment: Well, I don't know I guess. If there were a function that you send it an object and output a string-concatenated GET-qualified version of that object, I don't imagine a single loop will always deal with the input. Of course, a single-level loop will always "outperform" a multi-level recursion, but a single-level loop won't even handle a multi-level object, IMO.

Comment: @Jared: Yes, with a multi-level object I'd imagine you'd need recursion, but even then, I'd think you'd need a different function (or different sort of processing in the same function) since it wouldn't seem to make sense to have a new querystring key start as the value of its parent.

Comment: @patrick - Yeah, I'm pretty sure if I would have answered the question I would have overthought the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something that processes nested objects as well as arrays.

```
const Util = {
  isArray: function(val) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]';
  },
  isNil: function(val) {
    return val === null || Util.typeOf(val)
  },
  typeOf: function(val, type) {
    return (type || 'undefined') === typeof val;
  },
  funEach: function(obj, fun) {
    if (Util.isNil(obj))
      return;      // empty value

    if (!Util.typeOf(obj, 'object'))
      obj = [obj]; // Convert to array

    if (Util.isArray(obj)) {
      // Iterate over array
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++)
        fun.call(null, obj[i], i, obj);
    } else {
      // Iterate over object
      for (var key in obj)
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key) && fun.call(null, obj[key], key, obj);
    }
  }
};

const serialize = (params) => {
  let pair = [];

  const encodeValue = v => {
    if (Util.typeOf(v, 'object'))
      v = JSON.stringify(v);

    return encodeURIComponent(v);
  };

  Util.funEach(params, (val, key) => {
    let isNil = Util.isNil(val);

    if (!isNil && Util.isArray(val))
      key = `${key}[]`;
    else
      val = [val];

    Util.funEach(val, v => {
      pair.push(`${key}=${isNil ? "" : encodeValue(v)}`);
    });
  });

  return pair.join('&');
};
```

**Usage:**

```
serialize({
  id: null,
  lat: "27",
  lng: "53",
  polygon: ["27,53", "31,18", "22,62", "..."]
}); // "id=&lat=27&lng=53&polygon[]=27%2C53&polygon[]=31%2C18&polygon[]=22%2C62&polygon[]=..."
```

Comment: This was very helpful, since I needed something that could handle nested objects. Thanks @AamirR

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) 
{
  var p = [];
  for (var key in obj) 
  {
    p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
  }
  return p.join('&');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use npm lib [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' });
// Returns 'foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge='
```

Answer (score 0):

this method uses recursion to descend into object hierarchy and generate rails style params which rails interprets as embedded hashes. objToParams generates a query string with an extra ampersand on the end, and objToQuery removes the final amperseand.

```
 function objToQuery(obj){
  let str = objToParams(obj,'');
  return str.slice(0, str.length);
}
function   objToParams(obj, subobj){
  let str = "";

   for (let key in obj) {
     if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
       if(subobj){
         str += objToParams(obj[key], `${subobj}[${key}]`);
       } else {
         str += objToParams(obj[key], `[${key}]`);
       }

     } else {
       if(subobj){
         str += `${key}${subobj}=${obj[key]}&`;
       }else{
         str += `${key}=${obj[key]}&`;
       }
     }
   }
   return str;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = { id: 1, name: 'Neel' };
let str = '';
str = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`).join('&');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

We should also handle the cases when the value of any entry is undefined, that key should not be included in the serialized string.

```
const serialize = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([, value]) => value)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');
}
```

Comment: Fails to handle nested objects. Example: { "WHERE": { "createdOn": { "min": "2021-01-15", "max": "2021-02-16" }}}

Answer (score 0):

```
export const convertObjToUrlParams = (obj) =>
{
    var paramString = '';
    for (let key in obj)
    {
        if (obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== undefined)
        {
            paramString += '&';
            paramString += key + "=" + obj[key];
        }
    }
    return paramString;
}
```

**Output Ex:** &firstName=NoDo&userId=2acf67ed-73c7-4707-9b49-17e78afce42e&email=n@n.dk&phoneNumber=12345678&password=123456

Answer (score 0):

try this... this is working for array value also..

```
let my_obj = {'single':'this is single', 'arrayVal':['child1','child2']};

let url_query_params = ((o)=>{ return Object.keys(o).map(function(key){ let ret=[]; if(Array.isArray(o[key])){ o[key].forEach((item)=>{ ret.push(`${key}[]=${encodeURIComponent(item)}`); }); }else{ ret.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(o[key])}`); } return ret.join("&");  }).join("&"); })(my_obj);
```

Comment: That's not a nested object.

Comment: @Mukus ...ya sorry, my mistake..  that is not nested object, but that is array value... i just amended my answer... thanks

Answer (score -1):

## With `Axios` and `infinite depth`:

```html
<pre>
    <style>
      textarea {
        width: 80%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      label {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    <label>URI</label>
    <textarea id="uri"  rows="7"></textarea>
    <label>All Defaults (Bonus): </label>
    <textarea id="defaults" rows="20"></textarea>
</pre>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseUrl: 'http://my-api-server',
    url: '/user'
  })
  const uri = instance.getUri({
    params: {
      id: '1234',
      favFruits: [
        'banana',
        'apple',
        'strawberry'
      ],
      carConfig: {
        items: ['keys', 'laptop'],
        type: 'sedan',
        other: {
          music: ['on', 'off', {
            foo: 'bar'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  })
  const defaults = JSON.stringify(instance.defaults, null, 2)
  document.getElementById('uri').value = uri
  document.getElementById('defaults').value = defaults
</script>
```

Good Luck...