# How do I turn a javascript dictionary into an encoded url string?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get something like

```
?key=value?key=value
```

out of a js dictionary that is

```
{
    key:value,
    key:value
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `?key=value&key=value` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize an Object into a list of URL query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-url-query-parameters)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
var params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
var str = jQuery.param( params );
// str is now 'width=1680&height=1050'
```

Otherwise, here is a function that does it:

```
function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
     str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
  return str.join("&");
}
alert(serialize({test: 12, foo: "bar"}));
```

Comment: Use: `var str = $.param( params ); ` instead now.

Answer (score 26):

There is a much simpler way to do this now:

API for `URLSearchParams` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
var url = new URL('https://example.com/');
url.search = new URLSearchParams({blah: 'lalala', rawr: 'arwrar'}); 
console.log(url.toString()); // https://example.com/?blah=lalala&rawr=arwrar
```

Comment: You can convert the params only with toString method aswell:  
    `var url = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();`

Comment: Not supported by IE11 as per https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Answer (score 7):

The same in ECMAScript 2016:

```
let params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
// convert object to list -- to enable .map
let data = Object.entries(params);
// encode every parameter (unpack list into 2 variables)
data = data.map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`);
// combine into string
let query = data.join('&');
console.log(query); // => width=1680&height=1050
```

Or, as single-liner:

```
let params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
Object.entries(params).map(([k, v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`).join('&');
// => "width=1680&height=1050"
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  Can you explain the backwards accent marks and dollar signs?  I've not seen that before.

Comment: @kloddant It is the same as ' or " except that you can embed expressions in it. Ex. `text ${1+1}` // will output "text 2"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals