# Sending JSON to the Django backend

Tags: json, django, angular

I have an object in Angular

```
const obj = {name: 'someName'};
```

And I stringify it:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

And when I'm trying to send this data to Django backend (and then, backend try to deserialize string I get an error)

```
JSONDecodeError at /some_endpoint
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

And how request looks like in Chrome DevTools, in request payload

```
data: "{"name":"someName"}"
```

How to correct send this payload? Do I have to change data before send?

Comment: just send the `obj` instead of `data`

Comment: Then data in DevTools looks: data: {name: "someName"} and I get an error data: ["Value must be valid JSON."]

Comment: show the backend code

Comment: And the rest of your JS. Exactly how are you actually sending this data?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045065/how-do-i-turn-a-javascript-dictionary-into-an-encoded-url-string