# Javascript hash

Tags: javascript

I have this hash:

```
{
 a: [1,2],
 b: [1,2,3]
}
```

I need to generate a string like this:

a=1&a=2&b=1&b=2&b=3

How can I solve this problem ?
I'm taking a look at lodash but I cant solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you looking at lodash? Why not use a simple loop?

Comment: Maybe habe a look at [Convert javascript object to URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22678346/1048572) for some ideas

Comment: I would still hold off on ES6 solutions unless you **know** that enough of your users support the features you want. I'd stick to one of the simple loops that were proposed (including my answer)

Comment: **This is not a duplicate of the question shown**! A string like `a=1&a=2` would be *overwriting* the previous `a` variable. This is NOT what the original poster is asking for.

Comment: I agree with @Martin: Not the same question, and does not provide a suitable solution. Thus I have flagged for reopen... there *might* be a duplicate out there, but the proposed one is not it

Comment: If you're using jQuery [`$.param({ a: [1,2], b: [1,2,3] }, true)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/#jQuery-param-obj-traditional) results in the desired string.

Answer (score 5):

Using javascript **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** with **[ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

```js
var arr = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: [1, 2, 3]
};
var res = Object.keys(arr).map(v => arr[v].map(v1 => v + '=' + v1).join('&')).join('&');
document.write(res);
```

---

Or without arrow function

```js
var arr = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: [1, 2, 3]
};

var res = 
    // get object keys
    Object.keys(arr)
// iterate over object keys and iterate
.map(function(v) {
  // iterate over inner array
  return arr[v].map(function(v1) {
    // generate prefered string and return 
    return v + '=' + v1
    // cconcatenate string array
  }).join('&')
  // concatenate string array
}).join('&');

document.write(res);
```

Comment: Or, just for fun, instead of two `joins`, if the input doesn't contain any comas: `Object.keys(arr).map(v => arr[v].map(v1 => v + '=' + v1)).join().replace(/,/g, '&')` :)

Comment: The inner `.join('&')` can removed if you replace the outer `.map(...)` with `.flatMap(...)`

Answer (score 4):

## For a nice ES5 solution:

```
function hashToString(hash) {

    var str = '';
    for ( prop in hash ) {
        if ( !hash.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) continue;
        for (var i = 0; i < hash[prop].length; i++) {
            str += prop + '=' + hash[prop][i] + '&';
        };
    }
    str = str.slice(0, str.length-1);
    return str;

}
```

Try that out!

#### It works:

[image]

---

## Okay! So what's going on?

#### First, you want to loop through each item on the first level.

You do this with a [`for ... in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). You should be checking [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) so you don't go through unexpected prototype properties.

#### Then, within that first loop, you want to loop through the items in the *current* item:

We'll do that with a regular [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) because these items are just arrays.

In here, we want to adjust our string:

```
str += prop + '=' + hash[prop][i] + '&';
```

This adds our property name (saved as `prop` from the `for ... in` loop), then the value in that property's array at the given index `i`. We'll leave it with a trailing `&` that we will remove just outside of the loop.

Comment: I think you slightly exaggerated your answer, but it's 100% correct and useful. Grab a +1 :).

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit long winded. But when I started off, I learned *a lot* from long answers like this. They can show you not just the correct code, but the way to *think* when coding. I like to show what my train of thought is when I put it together, because often time that mode of thinking will help in future problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a for in loop to iterate over each property in your hash object, and from there, add each value to the string, like so:

```
function hashToQueryString(hash) {
    var query = '';
    for (key in hash) {
        for (i=0; i<=key.length; i++) {
            query += key+'='+ myJSON[key]+'&';
        }
    }
    //remove the trailing &
    query = query.substr(0, query.length -1);
    return query;
}
```

(Keep in mind that you should also be checking that each property in hash contains a valid array, and that you're not accidentally enumerating any properties you don't want)

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You could use [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) for that. It will also handle all the encoding needed if you happen to go beyond integers.

```
qs.stringify({
    a: [1,2],
    b: [1,2,3]
}, { indices: false });
```

Comment: this is why there are sooo many libraries, such a simple task with a couple lines of code, why a new library to do it :(

Comment: @musefan Those libraries free up your brain power so you could spend it on really creative tasks instead of ones that have already been properly solved by others.

Comment: @Li0liQ That's not a good reason to bring in a library for one task.

Comment: If you need the rest of the library, maybe... if you need this one tiny thing, then it's quicker to write own code than to find, install and learn a library

Comment: @Martin Fair enough. However, have you noticed that among the 7 answers suggested only two took into account url encoding? Isn't it a good enough reason to rely on a thoroughly tested library? And if the code volume is of concern, just use [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup).

Comment: Well the poster is not asking about url encoding. So no, I definitely would not recommend using a library for query string or url encoding.

Comment: @xyhhx If you see `key=value&foo=bar` you know it's probably either URL encoding or x-www-form-encoded. If you provide a solution without it, the next question of OP will be "How do I convert @ to %40 and $ into %24?" So accounting for URL encoding or at least mentioning that special characters must be encoding doesn't hurt.

Comment: @xyhhx Also, URL encoding is more complex than you might think. A lot of modern apps allow you to send structured objects via query parameters. `{a:{b:1,c:[2,3],d:{e:4}},f:5 }` is often encoded as `a[b]=1&a[c][]=2&a[c][]=3&a[d][e]=4&f=5`—where keys, values, `[` and `]` are URL encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stay with poor old ES5, and don't want to use *another library for a simple task*:

```
var myHash = {
   a: [1,2],
   b: [1,2,3]
}
var myString = '';
Object.keys(myHash).map(function(key, index) {
  myHash[key].map(function(value) {
    myString += (myString ? '&' : '') + key + '=' + value;
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/6ssuo4og/)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a cleaner way, but here is some options with reduce and map.

```
var obj = {
 a: [1,2],
 b: [1,2,3]
};

var params = Object.keys(obj).reduce( function (arr, key){
    arr.push(key + "=" + obj[key].join("&" + key + "="))
    return arr; 
}, []).join("&");
```

or if the values need to be encoded for the querystring

```
var params = Object.keys(obj).reduce( function (arr, key){
    var mapped = obj[key].map( function (val) { return key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(val); }).join("&");
    arr.push(mapped)
    return arr; 
}, []).join("&");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let hash = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: [1, 2, 3]
};
let str = '';
for (let key in hash) {
  for (let value of hash[key]) {
    str += `${key}=${value}&`;
  }
}
alert(str.slice(0, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple javascript hash one-liner I made named pr2:

`function pr2(str){let e=9833;for(let n=0;n<str.length;n++){const r=str.charCodeAt(n);e=43*e^r}return e>>>0}`

Though if that is not good enough for your purpose, here is MurMurHash 3:

```js
function murmurhash3_32(str, seed) {
    // MurMurHash is better than djb2, djb2 XOR, and FNV hash in speed, security, and collision probability.
    // Version 3 is better than version 2
    // Javascript implementation of MurMurHash 3
    // String must be ASCII only!
    // Seed must be positive integer only!
    var strLength = str.length;
    var remainder = strLength & 3; // strLength % 4
    var bytes = strLength - remainder;
    var h1 = seed;
    var c1 = 0xcc9e2d51;
    var c2 = 0x1b873593;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < bytes) {
      var k1 =
        (str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff) |
        ((str.charCodeAt(++i) & 0xff) << 8) |
        ((str.charCodeAt(++i) & 0xff) << 16) |
        ((str.charCodeAt(++i) & 0xff) << 24);
      ++i;

      k1 =
        ((k1 & 0xffff) * c1 + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c1) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
        0xffffffff;
      k1 = (k1 << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);
      k1 =
        ((k1 & 0xffff) * c2 + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c2) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
        0xffffffff;

      h1 ^= k1;
      h1 = (h1 << 13) | (h1 >>> 19);
      var h1b =
        ((h1 & 0xffff) * 5 + ((((h1 >>> 16) * 5) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
      h1 = (h1b & 0xffff) + 0x6b64 + ((((h1b >>> 16) + 0xe654) & 0xffff) << 16);
    }

    var k1 = 0;

    switch (remainder) {
      case 3:
        k1 ^= (str.charCodeAt(i + 2) & 0xff) << 16;
      case 2:
        k1 ^= (str.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xff) << 8;
      case 1:
        k1 ^= str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;

        k1 =
          ((k1 & 0xffff) * c1 + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c1) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
          0xffffffff;
        k1 = (k1 << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);
        k1 =
          ((k1 & 0xffff) * c2 + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c2) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
          0xffffffff;
        h1 ^= k1;
    }

    h1 ^= strLength;

    h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;
    h1 =
      ((h1 & 0xffff) * 0x85ebca6b +
        ((((h1 >>> 16) * 0x85ebca6b) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
      0xffffffff;
    h1 ^= h1 >>> 13;
    h1 =
      ((h1 & 0xffff) * 0xc2b2ae35 +
        ((((h1 >>> 16) * 0xc2b2ae35) & 0xffff) << 16)) &
      0xffffffff;
    h1 ^= h1 >>> 16;

    return h1 >>> 0;
  }
// end of function


  let string = prompt('string to hash')
let seed = prompt('seed for the hash (positive integer)')
let hashed = murmurhash3_32(string, seed)
console.log('Hashed: ' + hashed)
alert('Hashed: ' + hashed)
```

Comment: You must not have read the question in full. The input is `{ a: [1,2], b: [1,2,3] }` which should output `"a=1&a=2&b=1&b=2&b=3"`. So OP used "hash", probably because they didn't know any better. The intent is to encode the input, probably in URL query parameter format, but could also be x-www-form-urlencoded. As it stands, this answer is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to convert data to an URL query parameters, note that special URL characters should be URL encoded. JavaScript provides [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to build URL query/search parameters, without worrying about encoding special characters.

```js
const input = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: [1, 2, 3],
};

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
for (const key in input) {
  input[key].forEach(value => searchParams.append(key, value));
}
const desired = searchParams.toString();

console.log(desired);
```

Note that I use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iteration which iterates all iterable properties on the prototype chain. You could replace this easily if needed, for example with:

```
for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(input)) {
  values.forEach(value => searchParams.append(key, value));
}
```

Which iterates only the own properties of an object.