# Format string template with variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-formatting

I want to use a statically defined template for URL building.

I'm trying to use ES6 string interpolation feature for this

```
var template = "http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}";

var name = "John";
var age = "30";

var url = `${template}`;
```

Expected result: http://example.com/?name=John&age=23

Actual result: http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}

In case this can't be done with string interpolation is there any better method than `String.prototype.replace` like

```
var url = template.replace(/\${name}/,"John").replace(/\${age}/, 23);
```

Comment: That's the way they work; template expansion does not recursively expand substituted strings.

Comment: `name` is defined after template string is defined. `template` is not a template literal.

Comment: Similar question, albeit framed differently: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30003353/215552

Comment: It 100% can recursively assign strings - top comment is wrong.

Comment: Important question . . . you never actually state if the if the order of your variable definition is important here . . . do you **need** to define "name" and "age" after the template?

Comment: It seems the variables used within a string template need to be defined before its own definition. Otherwise all instances of variables will be replaced with `undefined`.

Comment: The word "template" has caused all kinds of confusion. Template literals do not create templates in the same way as templating libraries like Handlebars: all they do is string interpolation.

Answer (score 32):

The variables are substituted at the moment of evaluation of the literal, so you can't create a universal template that can be substituted with variables later:

```
var template = `http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`;
var name = "John";
var age = "30";

console.log( template ); // "http://example.com/?name=undefined&age=undefined"
```

Edit: fiddle for those who reuse a console session and have the variables defined from previous experiments: https://jsfiddle.net/nwvcrryt/

You also can not convert a string literal `"My name is ${name}"` to a template like what you're trying to do.

You can, however, use a function that takes the name and age and returns the desired url:

```
const formatUrl = (name, age) => `http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`;
let name = "John";
let age = "30";
let url = formatUrl( name, age ); // "http://example.com/?name=John&age=30"
```

Comment: This isn't correct. If you run the exact code you pasted in a browser you get `"http://example.com/?name=John&age=undefined"` in the console

Comment: @Phil nope, it shpuld be `undefined` twice: https://jsfiddle.net/nwvcrryt/ - are you sure you haven't reused the same console and have defined the name before?

Comment: That is only because they are assigned AFTER the template.

Comment: @Phinl which is why I demonstrate it as the flaw in OP approach (to have universal template that can be substituted with variables at run-time, which is not how template literals work).

Answer (score 16):

Here is how you would handle this issue if the values came after and you still wanted to use the template:

```
var template = (name, age) => `http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`;

// these come after template is defined
var name = "John";
var age = "30";

console.log(template(name, age));
```

---

This is if the question was in regards to recursion:

You used double quotes `"` instead of a backtick `

It will work otherwise:

```
var name = "John";
var age = "30";
var template = `http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`

var url = `${template}`;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kab48ht5/

---

If all you're trying to do is get some values into a proper URL format, you can try and follow this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678412/185672

Comment: Maybe I'm the one who misunderstood, but I interpret the question as "I want to have a template of the URL then build the urls by filling the variables later" (as in: the template should be re-usable, not a one-off call).

Comment: @Phil How much can this be helpful? Variable values are unknown during the template definition and are defined during the runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why this is particularly helpful and I took as someone who is trying to understand ES6's new string interpolation... honestly I would probably just encode an object otherwise

Comment: Oh, hahaha, I understand now. Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

As above mentioned, it is impossible to use variable as Template, perhaps, if you really need to implement it, and your environment is secure, you can use *eval*

```
var template = "http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}";

var name = "John";
var age = "30";

var url = eval(`\`${template}\``);
```

But again, use **eval** with **caution**. I recommend you to read [this](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) or similar articles before you start using *eval* in your code.

PS. I'm sure, there will be many people who'll downvote my answer because of it :D

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your issues/use case, but you should be able to do that without the "template" variable. . . just assign the value that you currently have assigned to "template" directly to "url" and use the backticks instead of quotes:

```
var name = "John";
var age = "30";

var url = `http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`;
```

That results in: `http://example.com/?name=John&age=30`

Comment: This will not work since variables are assigned after the template

Comment: Yeah, sorry . . . I meant to switch the order and forgot.  Fixed it.  I guess what I need to know was is the order of the variable important to him here, or is he just trying to get the interpolation to work?

Comment: I think it's both since without the proper order the interpolation doesn't work :-)

Comment: Kind of an important detail to know . . . they are two very different problems to solve (i.e., "How do I use string interpolation?" vs. "How can I define a string template **before** the variables that it uses?").

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
function sFormat(template){
    return data => {
        return Object.keys(data)
                     .reduce((acc, key)=>acc.replaceAll(`\$\{${key}\}`, data[key]), template)
    }
}

let first = "John"
let last = "Doe"
let age = 55
let someData = { a: 1, b: "foo" }

let template = sFormat('Hi ${first}! Your full name: ${first} ${last}, Age: ${age}, Data: ${someData}')
console.log(template({ first, last, age, someData }))

// "Hi John! Your full name: John Doe, Age: 55, Data: [object Object]"
```

Comment: Nice and concise smart solution! Just what I looked for!

Answer (score -1):

You'd use it like this, directly into the string.

Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals - credit to @jetpackpony

```js
const name = 'John'
const age = 23

console.log(`Hi my name is ${name}`)

console.log(`http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}`)
```

@Phil has presented a quick solution to the recursion problem, as long as you use back ticks on the initial template declaration.

With regards to the initial question (and the lack of a clear-cut answer) perhaps it's not explained enough. If you declare the template vars *after* the template literal, you cannot use them.

Comment: Could you also add a link to the docs to your answer please: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals