# Yet to be declared variables in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string at the top of my script with a variable in it that isn't declared yet, but I want to keep the string at the top of the script to make it easier for other users to modify. Is there any way to do that? Example:

```
const greeting = `Hello, ${name}. How are you?`;
```

Then in a completely different part of the code where the above `greeting` doesn't have `name` access:

```
const name = 'Steve';
sendMessage(greeting);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279852/format-string-template-with-variables-in-javascript/42280083#42280083

Comment: Read the answer of @OriDrori or try defining the `name` constant before you append the string to `greeting` constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function:

```
const greeting = (name) => `Hello, ${name}. How are you?`;

const name = 'Steve';
sendMessage(greeting(name));
```