# Unable to access posted data in php

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm using `reactjs` and `PHP` and trying to `POST` some data using `fetch API`. The data is posted successfully but the format of data is weird on server-side, that I'm not able to use it.

Here is part of my code:

**Javascript**

```
var url = "http://cyg.com/router.php";

var data = {
  service: 'Grade',
  programme: this.state.programme,
  enrolment: this.state.enrolment
};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(
  res => res.json()
)
.then(
  (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    //code to handle result here...
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    //code to handle error here...
  }
);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST); // here just to verify posted data. Remove later.
  $service = $_POST['service'];
  $programme = $_POST['programme'];
  $enrolment = $_POST['enrolment'];
  //some to code to process request....
?>
```

On posting data, it gives error that says undefined indexes `service`, `programme` and `enrolment`.

On Inspecting the `XHR POST` request in `console` of the browser I got following Params and Response of the request.

**Params**
[image: Format of data posted]

**Response**
[image: Format of data returned]

You can see in *Response* (2nd Image), the value of `$_POST` is in the format:

```
Array
(
    [{"service":"Grade","programme":"BCA","enrolment":"147996460"}] => 
)
```

I'm not able to figure out the reason of the problem. However, if I change the Javascript in the following way, everything works fine.

**Modified JavaScript**

```
var url = "http://cyg.com/router.php";

/*var data = {
  service: 'Grade',
  programme: this.state.programme,
  enrolment: this.state.enrolment
};*/

var data = "service=Grade&programme="+this.state.programme+"&enrolment="+this.state.enrolment;

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(
  res => res.json()
)
.then(
  (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    //code to handle result here...
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    //code to handle error here...
  }
);
```

On changing JavaScript, I observe a change in the format of request params too, It is as follow:-
[image: Format of data posted]

Thank You!!

Comment: I think you can just use `body: data,` instead of `body: JSON.stringify(data),`.

Comment: pleaes observer the first piece of javascript @u_mulder

Comment: As far I know that  `JSON.stringify(data)` method accept a javascript `object` and change it to `sting`. And In first piece of JavaScript, `data` is a javascript `Object`

Comment: _"if I change the Javascript in the following way, everything works fine"_ - so what's the problem then?

Comment: does it work if you use `json_decode` on the PHP side before trying to access the values?

Comment: The problem is that why the first way was not working. How the `POST`ed data become the `key` of the `$_POST` variable?? @Jeff

Comment: No @RobinZigmond

Comment: @u_mulder  _I think you can just use `body: data`, instead of `body: JSON.stringify(data)`,_ What makes you think so??

Comment: *"How the POSTed data become the key of the $_POST variable??"* ...... because you did that in `body: JSON.stringify(data)` . when you do `script.php?this will be a key in the $_GET parameters on the server`

Comment: So what is the write way to `POST`?? @Accountantم

Comment: @RobinZigmond, When I do `json_decode`, I got the error says : _Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in......_

Comment: @iNullPointer the body of the request should be url-encoded not a json string. check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678346/convert-javascript-object-to-url-parameters)

Comment: What is `fetch()` function on your javascript code? if you used something like jQuery ajax function that accepts parameter **data** not **body** it will convert the object to it's url-encoded format automatically. But it seems that the body parameter in your fetch function sets the body of the request as it is without converting it to url-encoded `foo=bar&zar=tar`

Comment: If I get it right, `fetch` do not url-encoded the body parameter but `JQuery` do. @Accountantم

Comment: @iNullPointer Exactly, you can do this : `$.ajax({url:"page.php",data:data,method:post})` and `$.ajax()` function will convert your "data" object into it's correct url-encoded format that your server expects. The body of your request is currently like `"{foo:bar,zar:tar}"` ,where it should be like `foo=bar&zar=tar`

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. @Accountantم