# How to convert Javascript object to a url string?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a Javascript object like:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Omer",
    age: 30,
    siblings: 3
}
```

Is there a way I can covert this into a string like this:

```
name=Omer&age=30&siblings=3
```

I have tried it with `JSON.stringify()` but it doesn't giving me the result I'm looking for.

The result is like this:

```
{"name":"Omer","age":"30","siblings":"3"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and `join()`

```js
var obj = {name: "Omer",age: 30,siblings: 3};

var str = Object
            .keys(obj)
            .map(k => k + '=' + obj[k])
            .join('&');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ob = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   key3: 'value3'
}

var str = "";
for (var key in ob) {
    if (str != "") {
        str += "`";
    }
    str += key + "=" + ob[key];
}

alert(str);
```