# How to read parameter from Request.Body in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest

Context: My application is behind a central login app, whenever the user apply access to my application, my application got a http request contain the user info. And I need to retrieve the user info from the HttpRequest Body.

This is what I tried so far:

```
currentContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["user-name"].toString();  // got nothing

using (var reader = new StreamReader(currentContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
{
    var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}   // I can get the raw HttpRequest Body as "user-name=some&user-email=something"
```

Is there any method I can use to parse the parameters and values from the Request.Body?
I tried the following, got nothing either.

`HttpContext.Item['user-name'] \\return nothing
Request.Form["user-name"] \\ return nothing`

and the reason I am not be able to use model binding is, in the HttpRequest body, the key name is "user-name", and in c#, I can't create a variable with a "-"

Meanwhile, in the my .net 4.6 application, `Request["KeyName"].toString()` works just fine.

Comment: You can use `Request.Form["key"]`. If it still doesn't work, please show us how you post the data and the entire action method.

Comment: last i checked there was no way to convert this into an object. This was because the usual way is to pass json to the body

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-url-query-parameters

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I am not trying to bind the parameters to an object. Just trying to the get the values. And the I have no control over the central login app. I believe the central login app is sending the parameters to my application using XML.

Comment: @Win I tried Requst.Form["Keyname"], got null.    And I don't have access to the source of the central login app. So I don't know how they are posting the data.

Comment: Why don't you use the normal model binding features? What about those don't work for you?

Comment: the deserializing part of the question i sent is the same. you can use the same method to deserialize

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a way to convert the raw `HttpRequest` Body to a Query String, then read parameters from it.

Here is the code:

```
var queryString = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(requestBody);

string paramterValueIWant = queryString["KeyName"];
```

There is one problem though, when the `KeyName` doesn't exist in the body, it will throw an exception. So you have to null check or do a try catch.

Still I feel like there should be a better way to read the parameter, as I mentioned, in my .net 4.6 application, all I need to do is `Request["KeyName"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we are talking about POST/PUT/PATCH call, you can use
`Request.Form["KeyName"]`
in your API method and set the 'contentType' of the Ajax request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
Notice that `Request` is automagically available inside your method. No need to explicit call it.

When using GET/DELETE call i prefer to use

```cs
[HttpGet("{UserId}")] // api/User/{UserId}
public IActionResult Get(int UserId){
  // do stuff calling directly UserId
}
```

Or with PUT/PATCH

```cs
[Route("User/{EntityId}/{StatusFilter}")] // api/User/{EntityId}/{StatusFilter}
[HttpPut] 
public IActionResult Put(int EntityId, int StatusFilter){
  // do stuff calling directly EntityId and StatusFilter
}
```

where you can then still take data from the Body using `Request.Form["KeyName"]`