# How to set correctly the React router query strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Route which I want to see all the time.

```
<Route path={`/:cardId??viewMode=:viewMode?&set=:set?`}>
```

How should I set the route path if I want:

1. cardId to be optional
2. Then to start my query params with the second '?' symbol
3. To set the viewMode and set optional BUT!!!! I don't want to see the 'viewMode' and 'set' strings if there is no options

I went through the docs but there is no info on how to implement this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-url-query-parameters

Comment: no, i need these params to be optional