# Reducing Object.entries() to a string and getting a random comma

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

Thank for the quick answers & yep as you guys pointed out it was an issue with the initial value. Also, following your suggestions I switched to using map and am now using,

```
const q = Object.entries(query).map(
  ([key, val]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`).join('&');
```

=========

Note: I am posing this question more out of curiosity because I ended up finding an alternative solution.

I have a query object

```
{
  artist: 'Jon Bellion',
  title: 'Kingdom Come'
}
```

and want to turn this into the string `artist:Jon+Bellion&title:Kingdom+Come`. My first attempt at this was to try to use reduce on the entries of the object as seen below.

```
const query = { artist: 'Jon Bellion', title: 'Kingdom Come' };

let q = Object.entries(query).reduce(
      (str, [key, val]) => `${str}&${key};${val}`
    );

q = q.replace(/\s/g, '+');
console.log(q);
```

This code results in `artist,Jon+Bellion&title:Kingdom+Come`. It is so close but for some reason there is a `,` instead of a `:` between `artist` and `Jon`.

I ended up switching to

```
let str = '';
Object.entries(query).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => (str += `${key}:${value}&`),
);
const q = str.replace(/\s/g, '+').slice(0, -1);
console.log(q);
```

Which gives me the desired result, `artist:Jon+Bellion&title:Kingdom+Come`.

Comment: the first entry is being used as is - read how reduce works differently with and without an initial value

Comment: Change `reduce` to `map`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23639793/6243352

Comment: personally, I'd use `let q = Object.entries(query).map(([key, val]) => `${key};${val}`).join('&');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't pass an initial value to `reduce`, so the initial value is taken to be the first entry, which is

```
['artist', 'Jon Bellion']
```

On the first (and only) iteration of `reduce`, it's turned into a string:

```
`${str}
```

Which means that the items in the array get joined by a comma:

```
'artist,Jon Bellion'
```

Either pass an initial value of the empty string:

```js
const query = { artist: 'Jon Bellion', title: 'Kingdom Come' };

let q = Object.entries(query).reduce(
      (str, [key, val]) => `${str}&${key}:${val}`,
      ''
    );

q = q.replace(/\s/g, '+').slice(1);
console.log(q);
```

Or use `.map` instead, which is a better idea IMO, since each segment of the generated string can then be joined by `&`, which is nicer than slicing the first `&` off:

```js
const query = { artist: 'Jon Bellion', title: 'Kingdom Come' };

const strs = Object.entries(query).map(([key, val]) => `${key}:${val}`);
console.log(strs.join('&').replace(/\s/g, '+'));
```

Comment: Yeah I missed the initial value smh. Also, map ended up being way better in the end. Thanks!