# How to pass javascript object as URL to django server

Tags: javascript, django

I have add_to_cart button in my html. When it is clicked, I want to take selected content and send it to my views.py. I have created an ajax request and I wish to send **item** object through URL to my views.py. Keep in mind that inside **item**, **toppings and extra** are NodeList. And I am using Django.

```
 add_to_cart.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    const item = {
        "item_name": document.querySelector("#itemname").textContent,
        "quantity" : document.querySelector("#quantity").value,
        "price" : document.querySelector("#price").dataset.price,
        "size" : document.querySelector(".size:checked").value,
        "toppings" : document.querySelectorAll(".topping:checked"),
        "extra" : document.querySelectorAll(".extra:checked")
    }

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', `/cart_item/${item}`, true);

    request.onload = () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (data.success){
            window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/cart_item/${item}`;
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login";
        }
    }
    request.send();
    return false;
})
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="cart"),
path("cart_item/<item>", views.cart_item, name="cart_item")
]
```

And in views.py

```
def cart_item(request, item):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        print("okay")
        messages.error(request, "Please login first to add to cart.")
        return JsonResponse({"success": False})
    return JsonResponse({"success": True})
```

Above is what I tried to do, but I get this error **Not Found: /cart_item/[object Object]**
I have also tried to search on Google the correct way to do this but could not find a satisfactory explanation. If you have a solution or an explanation on how to pass object in URL, please tell. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to send an object in the URL? You should look into serializing the URL parameters (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-url-query-parameters). Otherwise, you'll at least need to do `/cart_item/${JSON.stringify(items)}`.

Comment: Actually, I thought of using an Object because later on I will have to store the selected content in my models, so I thought it would be easier to access and store individual content if I used an object. Sorry if I am not making much sense here, but thanks for your input. @GhassenLouhaichi

Comment: If you use serialization on the URL, you can later deserialize the parameters into an object so you can store it like you said. You can do the same if you stringify the object in the URL, by parsing the string in the server side to get back to the object you want to store.

Comment: Coo!! I did not know that. Thanks a ton!