# Fetch() POST request in reactjs throwing error

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, access-token

I am trying to hit and endpoint which returns `access token` in reactjs using `fetch`. I am getting the error as:

> { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type" }.

Here is my snippet:

```
const response = await fetch(url,{
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
          //'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(
          {
            'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' : 'my_client_id',
            'client_secret' : 'my_client_secret',
            'scope' : 'openid'
          }
        )
      })
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong as in `POSTMAN` it is working fine with same params as above.

Comment: Your `Content-Type` doesnt match your `body` contents

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I have also tried to pass `'Accept': 'application/json'` in the headers but it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Why not `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`?

Comment: when I did that it gave error as `{ "error": "RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type" }`

Comment: So you need to convert to urlencoded

Comment: yes, in postman headers section I passed `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and it worked fine...am I missing something here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-list-of-url-query-parameters/43843090

Comment: You are missing the different formats. `urlencoded` looks different than `json`. You can't simply declare it `urlencoded`. You also have to serialize the data in the correct format

Comment: Postman was doing that for you behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks a lot @AbrahamLabkovsky. I have changed as `body:'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_client_secret&scope=openid'` and got the access_token now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help